# Extend Symfony to automatically escape latex characters for .tex.twig files

Tags: php, symfony, twig, latex, tex

I'm using `.tex.twig` files to generate some PDFs in my project. Per default, all of my twig files are autoescaped using `html` strategy. In order to stop unintended escaping, I had to wrap all of my `.tex.twig` files in a `autoescape false` block.
I want to keep the default `html` escaping for `.html.twig` files, but use my own latex escaping method whenever I'm rendering `.tex.twig` files. I've found a way to extend the twig environment with this code:

```
//LatexEscapeSetter.php
public function __invoke(Environment $twig)
{
    $twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')
        ->setEscaper('latex',
                     function ($twig, $string, $charset) {
                         // Escaping logic here....
                     }
        );

    return $twig;
}
```

In order to call this method, I created the following definition in my `services.yml`:

```
Twig_Environment:
    class: Twig_Environment
    factory: ['LatexEscapeSetter.php', '__invoke']
    arguments: ['@twig']
```

After restarting my server, I used `var_dump($twig->getExtensions())` and actually noticed that the core extension does hold a `latex` entry. But using `{% autoescape 'latex' %}` in one of my html pages as a test didn't have any impact.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you do it:

First you need to configure the autoescape_service and autoescape_service_method configuration under twig namespace.

```
twig:
    autoescape_service: 'App\Twig\EscapeStrategy'
    autoescape_service_method: guess
```

The escape strategy service must be registered in the config/services.yaml or your custom services definitions file:

```
services:
    App\Twig\EscapeStrategy: ~
```

In your use case EscapeStrategy could look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;
use Twig\FileExtensionEscapingStrategy;

class EscapeStrategy
{

    const STRATEGY_NAME = 'latex';

    public function guess($name)
    {
        if ('.tex.twig' === substr($name, -9)) {
            return self::STRATEGY_NAME;
        }

        return FileExtensionEscapingStrategy::guess($name);
    }
}
```

The symfony is using the FileExtensionEscapingStrategy by default so it is a good idea to fallback to its default guesser.

If you try to render the template which name ends with '.tex.twig' you'll get an exception since the handler for that 'latex' strategy does not exist.

To register a handler for new escape strategy you need to decorate a twig service. 
In services.yaml:

```
services:
    App\Twig\Configurator:
        decorates: 'twig.configurator.environment'
```

And the implementation could be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\Configurator\EnvironmentConfigurator;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\EscaperExtension;

class Configurator
{

    /**
     * @var EnvironmentConfigurator
     */
    private $configurator;

    public function __construct(EnvironmentConfigurator $configurator)
    {
        $this->configurator = $configurator;
    }

    public function configure(Environment $environment)
    {
        $environment->getExtension(EscaperExtension::class)->setEscaper(EscapeStrategy::STRATEGY_NAME, [$this, 'escape']);

        $this->configurator->configure($environment);
    }

    public function escape($twig, $string, $charset)
    {
        //implement escape here
        return $string;
    }
}
```

If you are not using autowireing check the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Also make sure to clear the cache regardless of dev or prod environment.

Comment: So, if I include another template like `{% include 'tex/template.tex.twig %}`, your guessing will enable the latex escaping automatically inside this template.tex.twig? This would imply that if template.tex.twig was like {% set x='&' %}{{ x }}, I'd get `\&` as  result?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a simpler solution.

Actually there is one helper class (a service) that uses this exotic escaper. It uses dependency injection to get the twig Environment.

There one can just set the escaper:

```
class TexHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Environment
     */
    private $twig;
    
    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig->getExtension(EscaperExtension::class)->setEscaper('latex',
            function (Environment $env, string $string, $charset)
            {
                // str_replace(['%', '&'], ['\\%', '\\&'], $string);
                return AppFilters::escapeTexInner($env, $string, $charset);
            });
    }
```

Now one can use e.g. `{% autoescape 'latex' %}` or `{{ myVar|e('latex') }}`